# $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ simply connected, $f$ holom. on $G$, show every connected comp. of $\{ |f| < c\}$ $(c > 0)$ is simply connected.

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

I have the tools:

1. $G$ simply connected $\iff$ every contour in $G$ has winding number $0$ about every point in $\mathbb{C}\setminus G$
2. $G$ is simply connected $\iff$ every holom. function on $G$ has a primitive.

**Ideas:** I could look at an arbitrary connected component of $S_{c} := \{|f| < c\}$ and use the primitive idea to say something about winding number? I tried to think about this and write some stuff down but I have no luck.

I tried showing (1) directly without any ideas from (2) but also with no luck. I even tried using the fact that $G$ is simply connected - I can write $G = S_{c} \cup G\setminus S_{c}$ and view $f$ on each set, but again I don't know where to go from here.

I am pretty lost on this problem. **I would like a hint, not a solution**. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to show a region is simply connected:

> $G$ is simply connected $\iff$ The interior of any simple closed curve $\gamma\subseteq G$ is contained in $G$.

Now take a simple closed curve $\gamma\subseteq \{|f|<c\}$. The interior $U$ of $\gamma$ is contained in $G$ since $G$ is simply connected. Then apply the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: Okay this is a good hint! I think I can say that $U := \text{int}(\gamma)$ is connected, whence $|f| < c$ on $U$ by Max Modulus ($|f| < c$ on $\partial U = \gamma$). Yes? So $U \subset \{|f| < c\}$. But wouldn't this imply that $\{|f| < c\}$ is simply connected? This is fine, but I only need that its conn. components are simply connected, so that seems fishy...

Comment: @Fred The set $\{|f|<c\}$ may not be connected, but $U$ is always connected by definition. So this argument only shows any component of $\{|f|<c\}$ is simply connected.

Comment: Okay got it. Choose $\gamma$ to lie in some component. Thank you for your help.